# Joomla 404 error administrator in localhost

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

A Joomla website works right online when i try to work it on localhost the administrator get a 404 error when submitting the admin log in data, what can i do ?

```
public $live_site = 'http://localhost/joomla_mart/';
```

Comment: Try using `public $live_site = '';` and see what happens

Comment: Still get the same error

Comment: Is this 404 error only for the admin page or the frontend too?

Comment: In the Admin page only.

Comment: Try renaming your htaccess file to `.htaccess`

Comment: That is its name already and it contain:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

Comment: I reload files and it works now right.